# Diferenças entre Commit Staged, Commit Staged and Push, Commit Staged and Sync?

Tags: git

Instalei o plugin do GitFlow e me deparai com 3 opções para fazer o commit.

> Commit Staged.
>
> Commit Staged and Push
>
> Commit Staged and Sync

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Qual a diferença entre eles? 
Quando devo usar-los?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Commit Staged

Commita localmente as alterações que estão na área de *stage*.

É equivalente a

> ```
> $> git commit -m "mensagem de commit"
> ```

#### Commit Staged and Push

Commita localmente as alterações que estão na área de *stage* e depois envia os *commits* para o repositório remoto.

É equivalente a

> ```
> $> git commit -m "mensagem de commit"
> $> git push
> ```

#### Commit Staged and Sync

Commita localmente as alterações que estão área de *stage*, faz um ***pull*** das modificações existentes no repositório remoto e envia os *commits* para o repositório remoto. Por isso o nome "*sync*", ao final da operação, seu repositório local deve estar completamente sincronizado com o remoto.

É equivalente a

> ```
> $> git commit -m "mensagem de commit"
> $> git pull
> $> git push
> ```